# HDMI to active dual link DVI (2560x1600px)

Tags: hdmi, dvi

Is it possible to go from HDMI to active dual link DVI with a resolution of 2560 x 1600px ? I have a Lenovo E540 laptop, and it only got a HDMI and a VGA out, but I have a 30" Mac Cinema HD screen, which only has a DVI connector. 
From several searches I can see that there are plenty of Displayport to active DVI converters, but none from HDMI to active DVI. Now is my question if it's possible to convert HDMI to displayport and go from there with a displayport to active DVI converter. Or is this not possible? If not, are there other possibilities?

Comment: nope, i'm asking if it's possible to convert hdmi to displayport, and go from there with an displayport to active dl dvi converter

Comment: It's not clear why you'd want to do that instead of go straight from HDMI to dual-link DVI, as you ask in the title and in the first sentence of your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Because as far is I know, there doesn't exist an adapter that can take HDMI and convert it to active dl DVI. If there is, then it would be a solution for my problem too ofcourse.